# Can't mount my external hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

I have an external hard drive which I partition sometime ago. I made two partitions in one I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and the other I use for storing various files. It was working OK last time I used it and that was about 3 months ago. Today I plugged it in and received this message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/shanks/515644a4-1492-4b80-b364-32b98755693b: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o  
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/shanks/515644a4-1492-4b80-b364-32b98755693b"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

In some cases useful info is found in `syslog - try dmesg | tail` or so.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and `sudo lsblk -f /dev/sdb` (or whatever the kernel name of your external drive is)?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with external HDDs using Ubuntu 16.04, 14.04 and 12.04, I'm assuming that is what you're attempting. I recommend using these as a base to troubleshoot from, then if needed remount the drive.

I start with Gparted to identify the device, usually its /dev/sdb1 or similar.

Then I find the device, there is a drop down in the top right (at the moment) to change between devices. Once you have located your USB device select it.

I like to use EXT4 format. To do so:

1 - select the HDD (usually sdb1 or similar) note the path for later use

2 - Right Click and choose Format

3 - Select EXT4 (or whatever format you like)

4 - Click on the Green Checkmark to apply the changes

5 - Label the device by Right Click and choose Label, I stick with EXT-HDD for my external HDD

6 - Click on the Green Checkmark again to apply the label

Here's where it gets a little confusing, and may be entirely based on the brand of HDDs I used, but skipping this step caused me issues. 
7 - After you have saved the changes, disconnect the EXT-HDD

8 - Leave it disconnected and shutdown (NOT REBOOT) your PC

9 - plug the EXT-HDD back into the same USB port

10 - turn the PC back on

11 - get to the desktop and open up a terminal and become root

12 - Identify the Devices UUID with this command and the path you noted from step 1:

```
blkid /dev/sdb1
```

13 - Note the UUID for the device

14 - Create the mount point you want with this command:

```
mkdir /mnt/exthdd
```

(or similar depending on where you want it mounted and pointing to) Note that mount point for later use

15 - open and edit fstab via terminal to look give it mount point and permissions

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

add the line (use tab between values):

```
UUID=<enter your devices UUID>     /mnt/exthdd     ext4     auto     0     0
```

16 - save changes to fstab

17 - give permissions to the created mount point

```
chmod 777 /mnt/exthdd
```

Exit terminal and reboot.

At this point your PC should boot fine and have a new mount point. Any issues start over and double check everything. There have been devices I can get mounted on the first try, and for some reason others take a few tries, so don't loose heart. To ensure it mounted, there should be no errors during boot also go to that mount point in your files and see what the size of the volume is, it should be about the size of your USB device.

Good Luck and Enjoy!